# how to skip the index in python for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a list like this:

```
array=['for','loop','in','python']

for arr in array:
    print arr
```

This will give me the output

```
for
lop
in
python
```

I want to print

```
in
python
```

How can I skip the first 2 indices in python?

Comment: why not `for arr in array[2:]:`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Code:**

```
array=['for','loop','in','python']
for arr in array[2:]:
    print arr
```

**Output:**

```
in
python
```

Answer (score 9):

Use [slicing](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists).

```
array = ['for','loop','in','python']

for arr in array[2:]:
    print arr
```

When you do this, the starting index in the `for` loop becomes `2`. Thus the output would be:

```
in
python
```

For more info on `slicing` read this: [Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation)

Comment: Since OP doesn't know about slicing he might not know you can do something similar using range or xrange if you're using 2.7. Just something else to think about

Answer (score 2):

See [Python slicing](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/introduction.html#lists):

```
for arr in array[2:]:
    print arr
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to skip other lines or want to try different combination then you could do this

**Code:**

```
for i ,j in enumerate(array):
    if i not in (1,2):
        print j
```

**Output:**

```
for
python
```

Comment: Wouldn't this skip the 2nd and 3rd items, since indexing begins at 0?

Answer (score 2):

**Slicing** is good, but if you're considered about performance, you might prefer `itertools.islice`:

```
import itertools
array = 'for loop in python'.split()
for x in itertools.islice(array, 2, None):
    print x
```

because the slice operator builds a completely new list, which means overhead if you just want to iterate over it.